# Is mRMR feature selection sensitive to imbalanced dataset?

Tags: feature-selection

I wish to perform feature selection on a dataset using mRMR but my classes are imbalanced roughly 3:1. Should I down sample the majority class or use the whole dataset? If I use the whole dataset will it select features that are biased towards the majority class?